# Custom domain for Github pages

Tags: github, dns

I have a following situation. I have one repository: [padsbanger.github.io](http://padsbanger.github.io) that points to my  [homepage](http://michal-lach.pl).

What I want now is to have another [repository](http://padsbanger.github.io/bioharmonic) pointing to diffrent domain, http://bioharmonic.pl.

Is that possible ? How can I achive this ? Do I need to set a CNAME record or A ?

Comment: Create a CNAME file inside the root of the repo. https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-cname-file-to-your-repository/

Answer (score 0):

You can create an organization and make GitHub Pages for it.

Or, usual repositories also can have pages. They're stored in a special `gh-pages` branch, but in other regards they're just the same.

https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/#project-pages